# django - multithreading queries

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django 1.8 and my logic requires queries in a loop.
I have multiple levels foreign keys:
Trucks->Boxes->Bottles

and thus multiple cascaded for loops.
The code below is over-simplified, but the only way to make it faster seems to be parallelizing the main loop.

I need to speed it up so I used multiprocessing as shown below.
The queries are read only!
This code with sqlite and postgres gets into deadlock.

A similar code on sqlite3 failed with:

```
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

I need to know how to speed this up.
If I'm required to put the model objects in a lock, then how should I do it to avoid too much locking

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from models import Truck, Box, Bottle

from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
MULTI_THREAD = True

def get_data_per_bottle(box):
    data = Bottle.objects.filter(box=box).values_list('color')
    data = [x[0] for x in data]
    return data

def get_data_per_box(some_param, truck):
    rows = []
    for bottle in Box.objects.filter(truck=truck):
        rows.append(get_data_per_bottle(bottle))
    return rows

def get_rows(location):
    trucks = Truck.objects.filter(location=location)
    some_param = ''
    data = []
    if MULTI_THREAD:
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        func = partial(get_data_per_box, some_param)
        data = pool.map(func, trucks)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    else:
        for truck in trucks:
            data.append(get_data_per_box(some_param, truck))

    return data

def index(request):
    rows = get_rows('usa')
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Bottle(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Box(models.Model):
    bottle = models.ForeignKey(Bottle)

class Truck(models.Model):
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Take a look at `prefetch_related()`. I doubt you actually need multiprocessing, you just have way too many queries.

Comment: @knbk. Thanks. It did speed it up a bit but it's still a bit slow.

Comment: I don't believe you're using `prefetch_related` correctly. Can you show your actual models and code?

Comment: @knbk I have updated the code and put the whole sample code; this code does a deadlock when I set processes=2